# Choosing the correct option for a symmetric distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, density-function

I have been given the following problem and I need to choose the correct one.

[image]

From the given probability description, it is clear to me that the term involving $x$ must have $|x|$ or even powers of $x$. I suppose this statement $f(x) = f(-x)$ mean that $X$ is symmetrical about point zero. Please let me know if this is not the case.

I am not sure what would be the implication of this? But after looking at the options I could find some counter examples.

Such as if I take $f(x) = 3x^2, 0<x<1$. For this pdf, although the condition is satisfied but the mean is not converging to $0$. So, the first three options seems to be false in this case.

But I am not able to figure it out why the last option would be correct?

Comment: Your $f$ is not symmetric.  For instance, $f(-1/2)=0 \ne 3/4=f(1/2).$

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the common distribution is symmetric about $0$. This means $X_i$ and $-X_i$ have the same distribution for each $i$. Independence of $X_i$'s then makes the last option correct.

The standard Cauchy distribution is a counterexample to options (1) and (2). As for option (3), I think a counterexample is the 't' distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom; here variance is not finite and so classical CLT does not apply.